# Problemas con NavigationStack y NavigationPath

Tags: xcode, vistas, navigation, swiftui

Recientemente he estado estudiando SwiftUI y me he encontrado con un problema tratando de diseñar una app para el registro de Usuarios. Tengo 3 vistas: Registro 1, Registro 2 y Registro 3. El objetivo es que cuando el usuario presione el boton siguiente en registro 1 se obtenga la respuesta de "Registro exitoso" del servidor y se pase hacia registro 2. El mismo procedimiento para Registro 2 y Registro 3. Cuando presione siguiente en Registro 2, el objetivo es obtener la respuesta del servidor y pasar a Registro 3. ¿Cuál es el problema? que puedo pasar correctamente de Registro 1 a Registro 2, pero no he podido pasar de Registro 2 a Registro 3 y he intentado buscar una solución por todos los medios y no la he podido encontrar. Las respuestas del servidor se obtienen normal, por lo que no he podido descifrar el error del NavigationStack. De antemano les agradezco por su ayuda.

```html
    
    
    Registro 1: 

        struct Registro1: View {
 
        @State private var path = NavigationPath()

         //Otro codigo no relevante
 
       func sendDataToServer() {
        let url = URL(string:xxxxxxx)!
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        let bodyData = "xxxxxxxx"
        
        request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: .utf8)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    if responseString.contains("ID existente") {
                        alertMessage = "ID existente"
                        showAlert = true
                    } else if responseString.contains("REGISTRO EXITOSO") {
                        
                        path.append("Registro2")
                    } else {
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }.resume()
        }
        
       var body: some View {
        VStack{
                    Spacer().frame(height: 100)
                    Group{
                        Text("Ingresa los siguientes datos:")
                            .font(.custom("Roboto-Medium", size: 25))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "F8CD57"))
                            .padding(.top, -50)
                        
                        TextField("", text: $Nombre)
                            .focused($isNombreFieldFocused)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 50.0)
                            .padding(.vertical, 12)
                            .frame(width: 328.0, height: 71.0)
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50)
                     .fill(Color(hue: 1.0, saturation: 0.046,  brightness: 0.938))
                                    .opacity(0.2)
                            ).disableAutocorrection(true)
                            .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                            .onTapGesture {
                                isNombreFieldFocused = true
                            }.overlay(
                                Group {
                                    if Nombre.isEmpty && !isNombreFieldFocused { 
                                        Text("Nombre completo")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                         .font(.custom("Roboto-Medium", size: 20))
                                            .padding(.leading, 0)
                                    }
                                }
                           

     // Otro codigo no relevante
                    
     Button(action: {
                            if validateFields() {
                                
                                sendDataToServer()
                                
                                userData.correo = self.Correo
                                
                            } else {
                                showAlert = true
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text("Siguiente")
                                .font(.custom("Roboto-Medium", size: 20))
                                .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "6E6A6A"))
                                .frame(width: 187, height: 69)
                                .background(Color(hex: "F8CD57"))
                                .cornerRadius(50)
                                .padding(.top, 40)
                               .navigationDestination(for: String.self){ view in if
                                    view == "Registro2"{
                                    Registro2()
                                } else if view == "Registro3"{
                                    Registro3()
                                }
                                }
                            
                        }
                        }
                        
       struct Registro1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            Registro1()
        }
    }
    
}
```

```html
   Registro2: 

 struct Registro2: View {

  @State private var path = NavigationPath()

  //Otro codigo no relevante

  func sendDataToServer() {
    let url = URL(string: "xxxxxxx")! específicos para Registro2
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    let bodyData = "xxxxxxxxxx"
    
    request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: .utf8)
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                if responseString.contains("Registro actualizado") {
                    
                    print("Navegando a Registro3")
                    
                    path.append("Registro3")
                    
                } else {
                   
                }
            }
        } else if let error = error {
          
        }
    }.resume()
}



var body: some View {

            VStack{
                    
                    Group{
                        
                        Text("Ingresa tu ubicación")
                            .font(.custom("Roboto-Medium", size: 25))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "F8CD57"))
                            .padding(.trailing, 70)
                            .padding(.top, 80)
                        
                        Spacer().frame(height: 30)
                        
                        TextField("", text: $Direccion)
                            .focused($isDireccionFieldFocused)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 50.0)
                            .padding(.vertical, 12)
                            .frame(width: 328.0, height: 71.0)
                            .background(
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50)
                       .fill(Color(hue: 1.0, saturation: 0.046, brightness: 0.938))
                                    .opacity(0.2)
                            ).padding(.trailing, 80)
                            .disableAutocorrection(true)
                            .autocapitalization(.none)
                            .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                            .onTapGesture {
                                isDireccionFieldFocused = true
                            }.overlay(
                                Group {
                             if Direccion.isEmpty && !isDireccionFieldFocused {
                                        Text("Ingresa tu dirección")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                        .font(.custom("Roboto-Medium", size: 20))
                                            .padding(.leading, -80)
                                    }
                                }
                            )

       Button(action: {
                            
                            sendDataToServer()
                            
                        }) {
                            Text("Siguiente")
                                .font(.custom("Roboto-Medium", size: 20))
                                .foregroundColor(Color(hex: "6E6A6A"))
                                .frame(width: 187, height: 69)
                                .background(Color(hex: "F8CD57"))
                                .cornerRadius(50)
                                .padding(.top, 40)
                                .padding(.bottom, 30)
                                .padding(.trailing, 70)
                        }
                    }
                }

    struct Registro2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            Registro2()
        }
    }
```

```html
Registro3:

      import SwiftUI

       struct Registro3: View {


    var body: some View {
         Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
        }
      }

    struct Registro3_Previews: PreviewProvider {
     static var previews: some View {
      Registro3()
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ensenas to `NavigationStack` pero el `path` de Registro 1 y 2 estan completamente desconectados.

`@State` es un "origen de verdad" debes de usar `@Binding` para una connection de ambos lados.

```
import SwiftUI

struct EjemploNavegacion: View {
    //Origen
    @State private var path: NavigationPath = .init()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            
            Button("Registrar", action: {
                path.append(RegistroPasos.registro1)
            }).navigationTitle("Home")
                .navigationDestination(for: RegistroPasos.self) { item in
                    switch item {
                    case .registro1:
                        Registro1(path: $path)
                    case .registro2:
                        Registro2(path: $path)
                    case .registro3:
                        Registro3(path: $path)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    enum RegistroPasos: Hashable {
        case registro1
        case registro2
        case registro3
    }
}

struct Registro1: View {
    //Conneccion
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        
        Button("Ir a 2") {
            path.append(EjemploNavegacion.RegistroPasos.registro2)
        }.navigationTitle("1")
    }
}

struct Registro2: View {
    //Conneccion
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Ir a 3") {
            path.append(EjemploNavegacion.RegistroPasos.registro3)
        }.navigationTitle("2")
    }
}
struct Registro3: View {
    //Conneccion
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Terminar") {
            path = .init()
        }.navigationTitle("3") 
    }
}

#Preview {
    EjemploNavegacion()
}
```

Comment: compañero muchisimas gracias, tus recomendaciones me funcionaron muy bien.

Comment: De nada `@LuisEnriqueMartinezMendoza si eso contesto tu pregunta puedes darle click al cheque verde para aceptar la respuesta?